# How to pass a RoutedEventHandler correctly to a UserControl?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, routed-events

I have a `UserControl` `c:MenuButtons` with an `ItemsControl` and the `ItemTemplate` is a `DataTemplate` with a `RadioButton`.

In the main wpf window I use the `UserControl` like this:

```
<c:MenuButtons x:Name="MenuProjects"
               SelectionChanged="{Binding d:MenuClick}"
               Height="35"
               MenuItems="{Binding Source={x:Static d:Main.Projects}}" />
```

I would like to have the `Checked` event of the `RadioButton` to bubble up via the `UserControl` to the `MenuClick` handler in the Main window code-behind and handle it there. This is a view-only thing so I do not use `ICommand` or model-patterns here.

The `RadioButton` `Checked` event is a `RoutedEventHandler`, so is `SelectionChanged` in `c:MenuButtons` and also `MenuClick` in my main window code-behind.

I cannot get it to work.

In the class MenuButtons I have the following code:

```
RoutedEventHandler handler;
public event RoutedEventHandler SelectionChanged
  {
     add { handler += value; }
     remove { handler -= value; }
  }
```

but the add is not entered despite the data-binding. Why not?

And: suppose it would be bound, how should I declare the binding in the DataTemplate?
I tried `Checked="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=SelectionChanged}"` which gives a XamlParseException on this particular attempt of binding (Unable to cast object of type 'System.Reflection.RuntimeEventInfo' to type 'System.Reflection.MethodInfo'.)

It turns out to be straightforward:
In the class MenuButtons you get:

```
public static readonly RoutedEvent SelectionChangedEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("SelectionChanged", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(MenuButtons));

public event RoutedEventHandler SelectionChanged
{
    add { AddHandler(SelectionChangedEvent, value); }
    remove { RemoveHandler(SelectionChangedEvent, value); }
}
private void RadioButton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    RoutedEventArgs eventargs = new RoutedEventArgs(MenuButtons.SelectionChangedEvent);
    RaiseEvent(eventargs);
}
```

In the xaml of the UserControl you add:

```
<RadioButton Checked="RadioButton_Checked"
```

And in the main form you have:

```
 <c:MenuButtons SelectionChanged="MenuProjects_SelectionChanged"
```

There luckily `e.OriginalSource` gives the information for handling the event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check those links out:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752288.aspx

And also this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx

The tutorials will show you how to create routed events and how to subscribe them properly to elements.

Btw, `add { handler += value; }` is wrong.

This is how you should write it : `add { this.AddHandler(MyRoutedEvent...);` }

Comment: Iv'e never seen an approach of setting a RoutedEventHandler via binding , i'm guessing this is possible because we can assign an handler in xaml with out a any problem ,
have you tried this out ?

Comment: its not possible thats why i gave the op links to follow